# Using reserved word with ejs

Tags: javascript, ejs

if I try to compile an EJS template like below:

```
var data = { case: 'Something' };
var html = ejs.render('Case <%= case %>', data);
```

I get the error:

```
ejs.js:550 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token case while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (ejs.js:550)
    at Object.compile (ejs.js:359)
    at handleCache (ejs.js:202)
    at Object.exports.render (ejs.js:385)
    at VM546 script.js:2
```

It's because `case` is a reserved word. Is there a way around it, given that I cannot change the JSON I'm feeding into EJS?

**Edit**: here's a link to an online Plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/WBpjom

Comment: You could place your data inside an object literal,.. eg.. `ejs.render('Case <%= data.case %>', {data:data});`

Comment: I am already doing that as a workaround @Keith, just wanted to know if there's another way.

Comment: Seen as it's just Javascript EJS compiles too, you could maybe try `["case"]`

Comment: @Keith it doesn't work, JavaScript thinks that an Array literal instead. You can play with it using the Plunker link I just added if you want.

Comment: try -> `var html = ejs.render('Case <%= locals.case %>', data);`

Comment: @Keith do you mind adding that as a response so I can accept it? It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like EJS, also set's a context called `locals` that is passed..

So..

```
  var html = ejs.render('Case <%= locals.case %>', data)
```